# Pass method argument to function

Tags: go, methods

I'm curious if this is possible in Go. I have a type with multiple methods. Is it possible to have a function which takes a method argument and then call it for the type?

Here is a small example of what I would want:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo int

func (f Foo) A() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}
func (f Foo) B() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}
func (f Foo) C() {
    fmt.Println("C")
}

func main() {
    var f Foo
    bar := func(foo func()) {
        f.foo()
    }
    bar(A)
    bar(B)
    bar(C)
}
```

Go thinks type `Foo` has a method called `foo()`, rather than replacing it with the passed in method name.

Comment: I don't understand what your asking. Is this what you're trying to do? https://play.golang.org/p/VXuSOeGPd-

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have 2 (3) options:

#### [Spec: Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

The expression `Foo.A` yields a function equivalent to `A` but with an explicit receiver as its first argument; it has signature `func(f Foo)`.

```
var foo Foo
bar := func(m func(f Foo)) {
    m(foo)
}
bar(Foo.A)
bar(Foo.B)
bar(Foo.C)
```

Here the method receiver is explicit. You only pass the method name (with the type it belongs to) to `bar()`, and when calling it, you have to pass the actual receiver: `m(f)`.

Output as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/d1sEoNOHUex)):

```
A
B
C
```

#### [Spec: Method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)

If `f` is a value of type `Foo`, the expression `f.A` yields a function value of type `func()` with implicit receiver value `f`.

```
var f Foo
bar := func(m func()) {
    m()
}
bar(f.A)
bar(f.B)
bar(f.C)
```

Note that here the method receiver is implicit, it is saved with the function value passed to `bar()`, and so it is called without explicitly specifying it: `m()`.

Output is the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FQ8Kwnv8yq)).

#### (For completeness: [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/))

Inferior to previous solutions (both in performance and in "safeness"), but you could pass the name of the method as a `string` value, and then use the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to call the method by that name. It could look like this:

```
var f Foo
bar := func(name string) {
    reflect.ValueOf(f).MethodByName(name).Call(nil)
}
bar("A")
bar("B")
bar("C")
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eCT34Da3Lr).

Comment: How would you do it for method with pointer receivers ? I tried like shown in this link https://play.golang.org/p/mdi8htBnZ9. But i cannot figure out.

Comment: As i could not edit previous comment, adding a new comment. I tried as given in spec and came up with https://play.golang.org/p/7P9mU0uhke. But i have one more question here. I was expecting the two addresses that are getting printed to be the same (address of Foo instance `f`)

Comment: @rajkamal Inside `foo.A()` you're not printing the `f` pointer but the address of the pointer. `f` is already a pointer, so `&f` will be of type `**foo`. If you change it to simply print the value of `f`, then you'll see the same pointer printed: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kfrOQVC494)

Answer (score 1):

I played with this wanting a state machine type component that doesn't use a map[string]func() for containing state methods. My code allows a run method
which is a simple for loop which breaks when pfunc == nil

```
type Foo struct {
    name string
    idx  int
}
type X func(*Foo) X

func (f *Foo) A() X {
    f.name += fmt.Sprintf(" A[%d]", f.idx)
    fmt.Println(f.name)
    if f.idx > 10 {
        fmt.Println("Foo is complete!")
        return nil
    } else {
        f.idx += 1
        return (*Foo).B
    }
}
func (f *Foo) B() X {
    f.name += fmt.Sprintf(" B[%d]", f.idx)
    fmt.Println(f.name)
    f.idx += 2
    return (*Foo).C
}
func (f *Foo) C() X {
    f.name += fmt.Sprintf(" C[%d]", f.idx)
    fmt.Println(f.name)
    f.idx += 3
    return (*Foo).A
}

func main() {
    bar := &Foo{"Ready!", 0}
    pfunc := (*Foo).A
    except := 1
    for pfunc != nil && except < 10 {
        pfunc = pfunc(bar)
        except += 1
    }
}
```

Output:
Ready! A[0]
Ready! A[0] B[1]
Ready! A[0] B[1] C[3]
Ready! A[0] B[1] C[3] A[6]
Ready! A[0] B[1] C[3] A[6] B[7]
Ready! A[0] B[1] C[3] A[6] B[7] C[9]
Ready! A[0] B[1] C[3] A[6] B[7] C[9] A[12]
Foo is complete!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the “method values” option listed by @icza with different receivers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo int
type Goo int

func (f Foo) A() { fmt.Println("A") }
func (f Foo) B() { fmt.Println("B") }
func (g Goo) A() { fmt.Println("A") }

func main() {
    //Method values with receiver f
    var f Foo
    bar2 := func(m func()) { m() }
    bar2(f.A) //A
    bar2(f.B) //B
    //Method values with receivers f and g
    var g Goo
    bar2(f.A) //A
    bar2(g.A) //A
}
```