# Syntax for Map with Callback to functions which have a receiver

Tags: dictionary, go

is it possible to create in golang a map containing functions which have a receiver?

I want to accomplish the following

**Function Callbacks:**

```
func (my *mystruct) doSometing(int parameter1){
// do something
}

func (my *mystruct) doAnotherThing(int parameter1){
// do something
}
```

**Map containing a pointer to the function**

```
var lookupMap = map[string]func(int){
    "action1" : doSomething,
    "action2" : doAnotherThing
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work because the callback functions are bound to a receiver. Go compiler says:

```
"undefined doSomething"
```

**My Question:**

What is the syntax to create a map where the values are functions which are bound to a specific receiver?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
var lookupMap = map[string]((*mystruct)func(int)){
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is possible. See possible duplicates: 1. [**golang - pass method to function**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/golang-pass-method-to-function/38897667#38897667); 2. [**golang function alias on method receiver**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### With Method Values

You may use [Method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) for this purpose. A method value is a function value with implicit receiver. Quoting from [Spec: Method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values):

> If the expression `x` has static type `T` and `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `x.M` is called a method value.

So the syntax for a method value is `x.M`, where for example `x` is a value of the type, `M` is the name of the method. This results in a function with the same parameters (and return types) as the method without a receiver, as the receiver will be saved with the method value and will be implicit.

So this means to store method values for your `doSometing()` and `doAnotherThing()` methods, the function type will simply be `func (int)` (no receiver).

Here's a working example:

```
type mystruct struct {
    name string
}

func (my *mystruct) doA(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("[doA]: I'm %s, param is: %d\n", my.name, i)
}

func (my *mystruct) doB(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("[doB]: I'm %s, param is: %d\n", my.name, i)
}

func main() {
    my1 := &mystruct{"Bob"}
    my2 := &mystruct{"Alice"}
    lookupMap := map[string]func(int){
        "action1": my1.doA,
        "action2": my2.doB,
    }

    lookupMap["action1"](11)
    lookupMap["action2"](22)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UhqqrV1Ngu)):

```
[doA]: I'm Bob, param is: 11
[doB]: I'm Alice, param is: 22
```

#### With Method Expressions

If you don't want the receiver saved in the dictionary (within the method values), you can go along with the [Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions).

The difference is that when you obtain a function value, you don't use `x.M` but `T.M`, which will result in a function value, with a function type having the same parameters (and return types), but the receiver type will also be in the parameter list, and in the first place. See quote from [Spec: Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions):

> If `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `T.M` is a function that is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as `M` prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method.

So the function type to work with will look like this in your case: `func(*mystruct, int)`

Also, since the receiver will not be saved, you have to provide it when calling these functions.

See this working example (which is the modification of the first example):

```
type mystruct struct {
    name string
}

func (my *mystruct) doA(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("[doA]: I'm %s, param is: %d\n", my.name, i)
}

func (my *mystruct) doB(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("[doB]: I'm %s, param is: %d\n", my.name, i)
}

func main() {
    lookupMap := map[string]func(*mystruct, int){
        "action1": (*mystruct).doA,
        "action2": (*mystruct).doB,
    }

    my1 := &mystruct{"Bob"}
    my2 := &mystruct{"Alice"}
    lookupMap["action1"](my1, 11)
    lookupMap["action2"](my2, 22)
}
```

Output is the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GpRYOJkjqt)):

```
[doA]: I'm Bob, param is: 11
[doB]: I'm Alice, param is: 22
```

---

See similar questions:

[golang - pass method to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/golang-pass-method-to-function/38897667#38897667)

[golang function alias on method receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088)

Comment: great! Thanks for the comprehensive answer! The Method Expressions did the job

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Method Values, this can also be achieved with closure scope

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mystruct struct {
    name string
}

func addCallbackToMap(lookupMap map[string]func(int), key string, my *mystruct) {
    lookupMap[key] = func(i int) {
        fmt.Printf("I'm %s, param is: %d\n", my.name, i)
    }
}

func main() {
    my1 := &mystruct{"Bob"}
    my2 := &mystruct{"Alice"}

    lookupMap := map[string]func(int){}
    addCallbackToMap(lookupMap, "action1", my1)
    addCallbackToMap(lookupMap, "action2", my2)

    lookupMap["action1"](11)
    lookupMap["action2"](22)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Rf1fiQK69ma)):

```
I'm Bob, param is: 11
I'm Alice, param is: 22
```