# What do you call (*receiverType).method(receiver)?

Tags: go

I recently learned that you can invoke a receiver's method by doing `(*receiverType).method(receiver)`, where the first parameter is always the receiver itself.

```
func main() {
    c := &Cool{}
    c.say("Cool!")
    (*Cool).say(c, "Hot!") // <-- this
}

type Cool struct {
}

func (it *Cool) say(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vVjr42ceqA

Is there a name for this kind of syntax? Why does this compile?

Comment: These are normal method expressions as described in the language spec here https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions. Rule of thumb: Look it up in the spec first.

Comment: See more on this here: [golang - pass method to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/golang-pass-method-to-function/38897667#38897667); and [golang function alias on method receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the links! You guys are awesome.