# Could adding variadic parameters to a function break existing code?

Tags: go, parameters, variadic-functions, backwards-compatibility

Is adding a variadic parameter to an existing Go function a breaking change?

For example:

```
// Old function
func Foo(a int)

// Updated to:
func Foo(a int, params ...string)
```

Callers of the API can omit the new parameter, so I  would think the API is backwards-compatible.

Can anyone provide an example where a user of the old API could not use the new API without changing their code?

Comment: Given that `foo` is unexported: Nobody cares. It it would be exported: It is a braking change. What that means for semver can be judeged by semverionistas.

Comment: I've removed references to semver, since that part is subjective. The question is now focused on whether this could break something, for someone. I've also made `foo` into `Foo`, since it only makes sense to discuss exported functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### I. Changing functions

Calling them will continue to work without modification, but since the function signatures do not match, that may easily break some code.

For example (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5LsWTXgv_iU)):

```
func Foo(a int)                    {}
func Foo2(a int, params ...string) {}

func main() {
    var f func(int)

    f = Foo
    f = Foo2 // Compile-time error!

    _ = f
}
```

The line `f = Foo2` produces a compile-time error:

> cannot use Foo2 (type func(int, ...string)) as type func(int) in assignment

So this is a backward incompatible change, don't do it.

The above example gave a compile-time error, which is the lucky / better case, but there may also be code that would only fail at runtime (non-deterministic if / when that happens), like in this example:

```
func Foo(a int)                    {}
func Foo2(a int, params ...string) {}

func main() {
    process(Foo)
    process(Foo2) // This will panic at runtime (type assertion will not hold)!
}

func process(f interface{}) {
    f.(func(int))(1)
}
```

Calling `process(foo)` succeeds, calling `process(foo2)` will panic at runtime. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F_aWjPusAMI).

### II. Changing methods

Your question was directed at functions, but the same "problem" exists with methods too (when used as [method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) or [method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values), for example see [golang - pass method to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/golang-pass-method-to-function/38897667#38897667)).

Additionally, this may break implicit interface implementations (it may make types not implement interfaces), like in this example (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/shVS4qJ6UM8)):

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo(int)
}

type fooImpl int

func (fooImpl) Foo(a int) {}

type fooImpl2 int

func (fooImpl2) Foo(a int, params ...string) {}

func main() {
    var f Fooer

    f = fooImpl(0)
    f = fooImpl2(0) // Compile time error!

    _ = f
}
```

Because signatures don't match, `fooImpl2` does not implement `Fooer`, even though `fooImpl` does:

> ```
> cannot use fooImpl2(0) (type fooImpl2) as type Fooer in assignment:
>   fooImpl2 does not implement Fooer (wrong type for Foo method)
>       have Foo(int, ...string)
>       want Foo(int)
> ```

Comment: since he is talking about callers of the api i would say it is not a backward incompatible change for the api users, since the old way of calling the api would still work

Comment: @Pizzalord It may continue to work in some cases, but it will break in other cases. The examples in the answers prove that. It depends on how it is used, but all uses cases in my answer are valid.

Comment: Most changes (even those accepted by Go, according to their backward-compatibility promise) have the potential to break _something_. Adding a field to a struct can break the ability to copy between structs of different types, but with the same fields, for example, but this is routinely done by Go. So whether this breakage matters for semver is, IMO, mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Flimzy I agree, somewhat true. But Go's interface design is special and very powerful, and if the function being changed this way is a method, that would break implicit interface implementations–which in my opinion is a serious change. Extending a struct with a new field does not imply signature changes.

Comment: I agree. Changing a function/method signature is a lot more significant than adding a struct field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've simplified my question a little, since it was getting people a bit angsty over semver ambiguities. However, you've still answered the new question - it's possible for someone to use my old API and be tripped up by the change. So it's a break change and I'll handle it as such. Thank you.