# Why typeof(method) does not return reflect.Method instance?

Tags: go, methods, reflection, types

Let's say I have Foo struct with a method defined as follows:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func (f *Foo) Get(a int, b string) (string, error) {
    return f.Name, nil
}
```

If I write

```
obj := &Foo{}
t := reflect.TypeOf(obj.Get)
```

`t.Kind()` returns `reflect.Func` and apparently I have no way to access information that `Get` func I extracted type information from "belongs" to the `Foo` struct, that is receiver is of `Foo` type, it is not even surfaced in the in-parameters.

I guess that's intentional and I miss something fundamental about functions that made language authors throw away receiver information for typeof operations applied to method references.

I have two questions:

1. Am I correct and there is no way to get receiver type in the snippet with `TypeOf` call above?
2. What are the alternatives I have if I want to pass reflection information about a method to some code that intends to analyze function and related receiver (that is, in essence a method)?

Trying to answer second question myself and based on what I see in the official documentation, it looks like my only options are to either pass TypeOf(receiver) and TypeOf(receiver.method) or TypeOf(receiver) and the name of the receiver's method.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values *The method value x.M is a **function** value that is callable with the same arguments as a method call of x.M.*

Comment: @mkopriva so can we call `t(&obj, a , b)` ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande not with a method value, the docs continue on to say that during evaluation a copy of `x` is saved and used in subsequent calls to the method value as the receiver, therefore &obj is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by mkopriva, what you have is a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values): `obj.Get`. And the method value is a function whose signature is identical to the method's without the receiver type:

> If the expression `x` has static type `T` and `M` is in the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of type `T`, `x.M` is called a *method value*. The method value `x.M` is a function value that is callable with the **same arguments as a method call of `x.M`**. The expression x is evaluated and saved during the evaluation of the method value; the saved copy is then used as the receiver in any calls, which may be executed later.

If you use a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) (instead of a method value), the receiver type "shows" up in the parameter list (it's always the first):

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf((*Foo).Get))
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9GrjyRKb2Bd)):

```
func(*main.Foo, int, string) (string, error)
```

The method expression:

> If `M` is in the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of type `T`, `T.M` is a function that is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as `M` **prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method**.

See related questions:

[golang - pass method to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/golang-pass-method-to-function/38897667#38897667)

[golang function alias on method receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088)