# How to pass a method reference in Go, like in Java?

Tags: go, generics

I'm rewriting my app from Java to Go,
I know the languages are completely different along with paradigms but still I managed to convert nearly everything.

Unfortunately I'm having trouble passing a generic function as an argument to another function.
In Java it looks like this:

I have an interface:

```
public interface Parser<T> {
    public T parse(String line);
}
```

Then I use this interface in a generic `fetch` method

```
public static <T> List<T> fetch(Parser<T> parser) {
    ...
    parser.parse(someLine);
    ...
    return the list of generic types
}
```

Then a parser method looks like this:

```
class Parser{
    static Foo ParseFoo(String line){
        ...
        some custom parsing
        ...
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
List<Foo> list = fetch(Parser::ParseFoo);
```

How do I achieve this in Go?

I've tried declaring generic interfaces, generic functions but I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Passing values that implement interfaces is easier / cleaner. But you _can_ pass methods, see [Pass method argument to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/pass-method-argument-to-function/38897667#38897667).

Answer (score 6):

An equivalent generic `Parser` interface would look like this:

```
type Parser[T any] interface {
    Parse(line string) T
}
```

Any type with a `Parse(string) S` method will implicitly satisfy the `Parser[S]` interface. For example, the following type `Foo` satisfies `Parser[int]`:

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f Foo) Parse(string) int {
    return 0
}
```

Then, with the generic `Parser` interface, you can implement your generic `Fetch` function:

```
func Fetch[T any](parser Parser[T]) []T {
    panic("not implemented")
}
```

---

#### Passing values that satisfy interfaces

How would you then do in Go the equivalent of passing Java *static method* like `ParseFoo()` below?

```
class Parser {
    static Foo ParseFoo(String line) {
      ...
    }
}
```

In Go, there are no static methods. Functions can be attached to types, in which case they become methods. As such, for the cases when you would have a static method in Java, you would normally end up with a *non-method function* or *standalone function* in Go:

```
func ParseFoo(line string) Foo {
    ...
}
```

To make this function satisfy the `Parser[Foo]` interface, you can define the following `ParserFunc` adapter:

```
type ParserFunc[T any] func(string) T

func (f ParserFunc[T]) Parse(line string) T {
    return f(line)
}
```

This way, from the standalone function `ParseFoo` – which isn't attached to any type – you can create a value of `ParserFunc[Foo]`, which does satisfy `Parser[Foo]`, and will just call `ParseFoo` when its `Parse` method is called:

```
f := ParserFunc[Foo](ParseFoo)
```

Finally, you can pass this `f` value to `fetch` since `f` satisfies `Parser[Foo]`:

```
fetch[Foo](f)
```

Note that you need to specify the type argument `Foo` to `fetch` as the compiler cannot infer it.

---

If you really need a method (i.e., like a non-static/instance method in Java), then you may want to look at **method values**. The procedure will be similar to the one exposed here.